# Custom Windows.Forms control in F# with custom OnPaint?

Tags: winforms, f#, custom-controls

I tried to implement a custom Windows.Forms control in F#, but my "OnPaint" method doesn't seem to get called at all (it's not displayed, and the debugging message doesn't print to console). What am I doing wrong?

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form(Visible=true, Text="Drawing App", WindowState=FormWindowState.Maximized)

type Canvas() =
    class
        inherit Control()
        override c.OnPaint(e:PaintEventArgs) =
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnPaint")
            base.OnPaint(e)
            let g = e.Graphics
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, c.Width, c.Height)
    end

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello")
let canvas = new Canvas()
canvas.Visible <- true
form.Controls.Add(canvas)

[<STAThread>]
Application.Run(form)
```

If I replace the "let canvas ..." block with the one below, a label *does* show in the window:

```
let label = new Label(Text="sample label")
form.Controls.Add(label)
```

Comment: Off topic: why not use WPF?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Why do you say off topic? I think the OP should just add some tags like `WinForms` Doing custom controls is tricky and doing them in F# I sure is even more tricky. I did them many years ago in C# to understand them.

Comment: @Guy Coder, Sorry, more I will not say off-topic. I often talk in chat and there permitted straying from the topic.

Comment: Truth said, I know really next to nothing about WPF, while I thought I knew something about Forms. Now it seems not much here either. Then, do you think I should better switch to WPF? Is it easier? to write a custom widget too? And purely programmatically? won't it force me to write XML ("XAML", yes?)?

Comment: If you don't mind I will answer in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f for not writing offtopic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [@FoggyFinder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36521803/98528), this is what I now converged on:

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form(Visible=true, Text="Drawing App", WindowState=FormWindowState.Maximized)

type Canvas() =
    inherit Control()
    override c.OnPaint(e:PaintEventArgs) =
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnPaint")
        base.OnPaint(e)
        let g = e.Graphics
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, c.Width, c.Height)
    override c.OnResize(e:EventArgs) =
        c.Refresh()

let canvas = new Canvas(Dock = DockStyle.Fill)
form.Controls.Add(canvas)

[<STAThread>]
Application.Run(form)
```

Seems to work for me, and looks more appropriate in my eyes. I will mark this one as the accepted solution for now, but I'm still interested in improvements if possible, or other propositions.

Comment: `let canvas = new Canvas(Dock = DockStyle.Fill)` =)

Comment: Right, that's certainly that much prettier, thanks! I'll add it.

Answer (score 3):

The line is not drawn, since c.Width = c.Height = 0.

Set Canvas size and get a result:

```
canvas.Size <- Size (form.Width, form.Height)
```

**Edit:**

That the Canvas size was the same as the form, enough to make the event subscription:

```
form.SizeChanged.Add(fun e -> canvas.Size <- form.Size; canvas.Refresh())
```

Comment: Oooook, helped indeed, thanks! But then, for completeness, am I expected to put it in some OnResize to keep it aligned with the form at all times? or should I rather dump it into some kinda Layout object or something to do this for me? I now start to recall that was apparently how one did it in Java, IIRC

Comment: Hm; the suggestion in the "Edit:" part doesn't seem to work well. The canvas doesn't draw initially for me, until *after* I explicitly resize it by hand...

Comment: What seems finally to work for me as of now, is adding the following to my example code: `form.SizeChanged.Add(fun e -> canvas.Refresh())` and `canvas.Dock <- DockStyle.Fill`. But I'm still interested in something more concise, this doesn't really convince me yet.